# DirectoryEntry.Properties["Path"].Value.ToString(); IIS7 issue. C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, iis-6, iis-7.5

Currently getting `Unknown error (0x80005000)` - Linked to "COM Exception" in C# when running the following code
`string virtualDirectory = GetVirtualDirPath("IIS://localhost", "1", reportUrl);`

```
static string GetVirtualDirPath(string iisHost,
                                 string siteName, string vdName)
    {
        string adsiPath = iisHost + "/W3SVC/" + siteName + "/Root/test/" + vdName;

        try
        {
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(adsiPath);
            return entry.Properties["Path"].Value.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // If Virtual Directory is not found,
            // it will throw exception.
            return "";
        }

        return "";
    }
```

I have setup "share" as a Virtual Directory inside "/test" (http://localhost/test/share) and tried giving that folder relevant permissions.

I have read that this only works in IIS6 and Not IIS7? If so, what is the equivalent code?

Comment: have a look at this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2428673, might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS7 now exposes a managed management API, information of which can be [found here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/284/using-managed-apis-in-iis-7/).

More specifically, there are classes to facilitate management of virtual directories.

```
var iis = new ServerManager();
var site = iis.Sites["SiteName"];
var application = site.Applications["ApplicationName"];
var directories = application.VirtualDirectories;
//proceed to determine the physical path of appropriate directory
var path = directories[0].Path;
```

Comment: @mrDisappointment - Looks promising, which Namespace does the ServerManager sit under? I will try this approach out!